# How can I survive after genociding my species?

Tags: nethack

I am playing nethack for the unofficial conduct of extinctionist.

So I am trying to kill every monster, but that is a bit slow without genociding some.   I want to be able to genocide `@` and `h`, but then I can't be those races.

Is there any way I can survive that?  i.e. amulet of life-saving, polymorph, etc.

Comment: Yes, the title is a *bit* provocative...

Comment: note that genociding species without 120 of them being born first is generally not considered to fulfill the extinctionist conduct...

Comment: @Wooble really? I didn't know that.  Well, this is going to be hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother.  You [can't genocide](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Genocide#Restrictions_on_genocide) most `@` anyway.  The game will just [tell you](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Scroll_of_genocide) that "[y]ou aren't permitted to genocide <monster>" repeatedly for several different classes of monster (it will succeed for a small number of classes including your own).

Genociding `h` is an entirely different story, and a good idea for any race other than dwarf (which has to play the polymorph/amulet-of-unchanging game, denying you a perfectly good amulet slot).  If you are playing as a dwarf, the usual strategy is to genocide the two mind flayer classes individually (i.e. with uncursed scrolls of genocide).  This is a lot cheaper than permanently burning an amulet slot.  Note that you must be very careful to spell it correctly: it is "[master] mind flayer," not "[master] mindflayer."  The latter might be interpreted as an attempt to genocide "master," which is [dangerous](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.games.roguelike.nethack/DSdZIMc87XY) if you are playing as a monk.

Answer (score 7):

According to [the wiki](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Genocide) the only way to survive genociding your own race/role is to already be polymorphed into something else and **never change back.** Nothing else will save you, and if you do change back you will instantly die.

Also note that you [cannot polymorph](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Polymorph#Restrictions_on_polymorphing) into a creature that has been genocided, so you are going to have to manually kill all of something anyway. It might as well be your own species.

Comment: Okay thanks.  My wanting to genocide @ was because that covers a lot of monsters, so this is probably the best shot. Thanks.

Comment: @RikerW While @ may cover a lot of possibilities, a large proportion of them are Uniques or exist only on the Quest level of "other" Classes.  There's only one Medusa. There is a handful of Town Watch.  Elves & Soldiers are the only real recurring threat in the @ family.

Comment: Note that genociding `@` will kill you regardless of your starting race; the only way to survive it is to be polymorphed.  Starting as a dwarf, gnome, or orc will not let you get around this.